# Search box locations - SharePoint Online (Modern)

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, modern-experience, search-box, microsoft-search

When I load up a SPO site (Edge or Chrome) the search box appears on the main Office bar at the top.  The sites are set to the Modern experience.  Communications template sites.

However, we've got users where it appears on the far right of the site nav menu... and for another, to the far-left of the document library toolbar.  Different sites, but same search box locations on Edge or Chrome for each user.

Attached is a screenshot to help illustrate this.  This is from my computer, so the search bar appears 'correctly' top-centre.  The blue boxes represent the locations it appears in.

I'm on Targeted release.

Is anyone able to explain why the Search fields appear in different places?

Thank you!

[image: screenshot1:search bar locations]

Search bar - nav menu: SurfacePro (2736 x 1824 resolution):
[image: screenshot2:search bar - menu bar]

Search bar - Document library:
[image: screenshot3:search bar - document library]

Comment: Are you using a team site or communication site templates?

Comment: Hi Ganesh.  Ah yes, sorry should have said - a Communications site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Previous Scenarios**

If You are using:

**Communication Site**: The Search box will be in the **site header** section.

**Team Site**: The Search box will be in the **command bar** section.

---

From recent announcements from Microsoft,

> The major experience change is the removal of the search box in modern experiences from where it was in the site header in communication sites, or the command bar in team sites.
>
> A new search box connecting our users to Microsoft Search will be shown at the top of the page in the suite header instead, and provide a consistent place to access search functionality. Similar changes are rolling out to other experiences across Office 365: Office.com, Office desktop applications, Outlook on the web, etc.

**Source**: [Search box changes in modern SharePoint and OneDrive experiences](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-search/search-box-changes-in-modern-sharepoint-and-onedrive-experiences/m-p/645596).

So, I guess this is still rolling out for some of the customers. Even I am not able to see the change in my office 365 tenants.

But, If you see any negative effects of this change then [follow this link](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR_eHQi_C8iFPulwhd4EJ0IxUOExTNTVBUlBISENGTVAzRUhMUTlWQUQ2Si4u) & tell Microsoft team more about it and they will help you.